# What is a シドギャ? ギャ doesn't mean girl, does it?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, slang, definitions

At first I thought ギャ meant girl, but after doing some googling, that doesn't appear to be what it is. What is シドギャ?

シドギャ is related to the band シド, the most popular Visual Kei rock band in Japan for all of you who don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

シドギャ is short for シドギャル, so ギャ is indeed "girl." シドギャ refers to (usually female) fans of シド (SID). A similar word is バンギャ (likewise short for バンギャル), which refers to (again usually female) fans of visual kei bands.

Comment: Then what does this say? 夫婦揃ってシドギャな僕たちの赤ちゃんがもうすぐ生まれてきます。なにか一言いただけたら幸いです･･･！

Comment: @languagehacker: A rough translation would be, "My [wife/husband] and I, both fans of SID, will soon have our baby. It would be wonderful if we got just a comment! [probably from SID?]" I assume it is the husband writing this because of the use of 僕, but this isn't necessarily true. シドギャ here is being used for fans of SID in general, rather than just girls as was its origin. Also, **please ask the question you want the answer to** from now on.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_(band)